# Why do I get "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc" when trying to reference a specific cell in a pandas df column?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand there are a few ways to access the value in a specific cell in a dataframe including "iloc". When I try to use iloc, however, I keep getting the same error - I also tried to switch it up and "loc" instead but get a different error (to be specific indexError). The code snipped is as follows: List_of_dfs is a list of dfs in which each df has the same column. 'Sex' is one such column with either 'M' or 'F' entries.

```
New_list_of_lists = 
[[(List_of_dfs[i]['HMW_Dosage_ISR']).max(),
(List_of_dfs[i]['Dose per Administration']).sum(),
List_of_dfs[i]['Sex'].iloc[0],
List_of_dfs[i]['ISR_Flag'].any()] for i in range(0,len(subject_IDs))]
```

Here's what I get:

```
List_of_dfs[i]['ISR_Flag'].any()] for i in range(0,len(subject_IDs))]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

I tried commenting out the line with 'Sex' column and it works fine, so the issue is with this specific column. More background - when I do "List_of_dfs[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zActC.png)['Sex'].dtype, I get "dtype('O')".

Any thoughts? I basically just want to be able to extract the specific gender and store it in the corresponding position in New_list_of_lists. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Edited to include sample data:

List_of_dfs looks like this:
[List_of_dfs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zActC.png)

```
Each df in List_of_dfs has several columns, with the following being of interest:
1) HMW_Dosage_ISR: dtype = float64
2) Dose per Administration: dtype = float64
3) Sex: dtype = 'O' - this value can either be 'M' or 'F'
4) ISR_Flag: dtype = bool
```

Comment: You should include a sample of your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you run `List_of_dfs[i]['Sex']` then you will notice that you recover a `pd.series` of type `str`. Since `.iloc` is a method of `pd.DataFrame`, calling `iloc` on strings objects will yield that error. Bottom line, you want to call `iloc` on Dataframes, not series

To make your code work do this

```
List_of_dfs[i].iloc[0, column_number_of_sex]
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried doing this but instead get the following error: raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')

IndexingError: Too many indexers

Comment: well, since you don't provide sample data it is hard for us to give you accurate feedback. The error that you're commenting comes from code that is unknown to me, so please include what you're actually doing

Comment: Just edited to include more details on the data - hope this helps?

Comment: not really lol, you have 264 columns? you still haven't show me how are you calling the .iloc under my suggestion

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe `List_of_dfs[i]`, then the syntax for accessing the first value of the `['Sex']` column is `List_of_dfs[i].at[0, 'Sex']` or `List_of_dfs[i].loc[:, 'Sex'].at[0]`

Comment: Thank you!! Tried this as well, but get the following error for both variations...any thoughts why? "raise ValueError("At based indexing on an non-integer "

ValueError: At based indexing on an non-integer index can only have non-integer indexers"